# tricky linked list problem

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity

Given three lists: A, B and C of length n each. if any 3 three numbers (1 from each list), sum up to zero return true.I want to solve this with o(n)complexity.I have sorted the lists and I can think of creating either a hash map with sum of 2 linked lists or comparing 3 lists together[o(n*n*n)].Suggest some ways to improvise the methods to reduce complexity..I can't think of any...Thanks in adv

Comment: can you explain with a little example?

Comment: Do you have access to just the heads of the lists or the tails also?  Are they singly or doubly linked?  Is there any info on how many nodes there are in each one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not think it is possible in `o(n²)` (i.e. really *better* than `n²`), but it can be done in `O(n²)` (i.e. sth. like `n²`) as follows:

First of all, reverse list `B` to obtain `B'` (takes `O(n)` time), a list whose items are sorted in descending order. First, we consider the problem of finding two elements in the lists `A` and `B'` that sum to any given number:

We can do this like the following (Python code):

```
def getIndicesFromTwoArrays(A,B,t):
    a,b=0,0
    while(A[a]+B[b]!=t):
        b=b+1
        if b==len(B):
            return (-1,-1)
        if A[a]+B[b]<t:
            a=a+1
            b=b-1
            if a==len(A):
                return (-1,-1)
    return (a,b)
```

Run time of the above is `O(n)`. Additional space required is `O(1)` since we only have to store two pointers. Note that the above can be easily transformed such that it works with doubly linked lists.

Then, overall we just have to do the following:

```
def test(A,B,C):
    B.reverse()
    for c in C:
        if getIndicesFromTwoArrays(A, B, c) != (-1,-1):
            return True
    return False
```

That results in running time `O(n²)` and additional space `O(1)`.

Answer (score 7):

The lists are sorted, right? Build a sorted array *C'* out of *C* in O(*n*) time.

For each of the *n*² pairs *x*, *y* in *A* × *B*, check if -(*x* + *y*) is in *C'* with binary search. Total time complexity is O(*n*² lg *n*), space complexity is O(*n*).

Building a hash table out of *C* brings the time complexity down further to O(*n*²), at the expense of belief in O(1) hash tables.

Comment: @Yochai: O(n²) when using a hash table. I don't see any faster way.

Comment: You can solve the problem for two sorted lists in O(n), so anything worse than O(n²) is suboptimal. However, you don't need to do a binary search, and you don't need a hash table. If you iterate over the n² pairs in A × B in such a way that their sums form n ascending subsequences, you can find the corresponding values in C in n iterations over it (one iteration per subsequence).

Comment: @aaz: my solution was really meant as a quick proof that it can be done in less than O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with O(n) complexity since it's NP-complete problem (unless P=NP). Check out [Wiki page about Subset Sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) for possible solutions.

Comment: This isn't the subset-sum problem, since there is the added restriction that only 3 numbers are picked, and they come from 3 different lists. For example, it's trivial to solve this in O(n^3), so it isn't NP-complete (assuming P!=NP).